# Подключение Java 3d к IntelijIdea

Tags: ide, java, intellij-idea

Подскажите, можно ли в IntelijIdea 7.0.2 подключить библиотеку java3d. Если возможно подключение этой библиотеки, напишите, как ее нужно подключить к Idea.

Comment: А в чём, собственно, сложность? И зачем вам такая старая версия?

Comment: Просто я работаю в этой версии, а новую еще не устанавливал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не знаю как в 7.0.2, но в 9й и 10й это выглядит примерно так

1. открываете Project Structure
2. выбираете Libraries Жмёте на плюс
3. Выбираете модуль(и)
4. Появляется библиотека Untitled.. даёте ей имя типа Java3D
5. Жмёте Attach Classes или Attach Jar Directories, выбираете
       jar'ы из Java3D
6. Жмёте OK

Comment: Спасибо за совет "cy6erGn0m"